# How to interface a "pull" library with a "push" library using callbacks

Tags: c++, embedded

I am using a driver that retrieves data from HW (Driver) and a display (Viewer) that will output data to the user.

The user calls a trigger function to initiate the getting of data from the Driver. The Driver's constructor accepts a "publish" callback function to be called when data is ready.

The Viewer receives a "get data" callback on construction, to be called when it wants data from my code.

My code must integrate the "pull" for data from the viewer with the data "pushed" back from the Driver once I call its trigger function. Another block of code (that I do not have access to) initiates requests from the Viewer and acts upon the data it received back.

This is represented by the main method in my example, below.

Thanks in advance!

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Viewer
{
public:
    Viewer(std::function<void(int&)> get_data_cb) : m_get_data_cb(get_data_cb)
    {
    }
    void populate_view(int &data)
    {
        m_get_data_cb(data);
    }

private:
    std::function<void(int&)> m_get_data_cb;
};

class Driver
{
public:
    Driver(std::function<void(int&)> publish_data_cb) : m_publish_data_cb(publish_data_cb)
    {
    }
    void trigger_event()
    {
        // tells RTL to start collecting data
        ++rtl_int;
        // trigger_event does not call the IRQ - this is just for demo purposes
        event_IRQ_handler();
    }
    void event_IRQ_handler()
    {
        // fires when RTL has finished collecting data
        m_publish_data_cb(rtl_int);
    }

private:
    std::function<void(int&)> m_publish_data_cb;
    int rtl_int{ 0 };
};

/**********************************************************************/
// Code I have control of starts here

volatile uint32_t publish_count{0};
int my_int{0};

// callback to send to Driver
void my_publish_data_cb(int &i)
{
    my_int = i;
    ++publish_count;
}

Driver my_driver = Driver{ my_publish_data_cb };

// callback to send to Viewer
void my_get_data_cb(int &i)
{
    uint32_t before = publish_count;
    my_driver.trigger_event();
    // I need to give the driver's event_IRQ_handler() time
    // to get the data but is this the best way???
    while (before == publish_count){};
    i = my_int;
    //cout << "Viewer: i =" << i << endl;
}

Viewer my_viewer = Viewer{ my_get_data_cb };

// Code I have control of ends here
/**********************************************************************/

int main()
{
    my_viewer.populate_view(my_int);
    std::cout << "my_int = " << my_int << std::endl;
    my_viewer.populate_view(my_int);
    std::cout << "my_int = " << my_int << std::endl;
    my_viewer.populate_view(my_int);
    std::cout << "my_int = " << my_int << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want this code reviewed or you have some other question?

Comment: Doesn't compile, because `uint32_t` is undefined.  Did you intend `std::uint32_t` from `<cstdint>`?

Comment: Good catch Toby. I missed that when I copy/pasted it in Sorry about that. It's fixed now

Comment: ALX23z: I am looking for a review. Thanks

Comment: You need to call `my_driver.trigger_event();` (in the real code), otherwise the driver callback won't get called, right? And the driver callback (in the real code) is called in an interrupt context?

Comment: Oh, and another questions: Is it required for the viewer to get new data everytime its callback is called? Or can it "show" the same data multiple times without issue?

Comment: You tagged the question "embedded". What kind of embedded device are you planning to run this on? Can you use C++'s [thread-related functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread)?

Comment: Daniel Jour: correct, my_driver.trigger_event() must be called for the driver callback to get called. It is also correct that the driver (publish data) callback is called from an interrupt context. Finally, it is optimal that new data is retrieved, however not absolutely necessary.

G. Sliepen: the code is running on an ArmV8 processor running FreeRTOS, so thread related functions can be used but I do not have access to the driver code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a busy-loop to wait for `publish_count` to be incremented by the interrupt handler. In general, this is a bad way to wait for something to happen, as it keeps the processor busy, which wastes power and might increase its temperature unnecessarily. However, in an embedded device that is not battery-powered, it might be fine. If the device has a single CPU core, then some compilers will even detect what you are doing and insert a CPU instruction in the loop that will pause the processor until an interrupt occurs, thus avoiding wasting power. However, that will not work on multi-core processors.

Since you mentioned the code is running on FreeRTOS, you can use its functions to suspend a task, and resume it from within the interrupt handler, for example using [`xTaskResumeFromISR()`](https://www.freertos.org/taskresumefromisr.html).

Another option is to use a [queue](https://www.freertos.org/a00018.html) to send information from the ISR to a task. This decouples the task from the ISR, which might have some advantages. For example, in your code, `my_get_data_cb()` will always wait for the IRQ handler to generate a new value, but maybe there was already a new value available if the IRQ fired between two calls to `my_get_data_cb()`, in which case the latter could have returned it immediately. Furthermore, with queues you can send data larger than an `int` without having to worry about atomicity.

Comment: G. Sliepen: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, I cannot change the Driver class code so would not be able to use a queue to pass info btwn tasks. or xTaskResumeFromISR since the ISR would require knowledge of the task handle.

The system is not battery powered and the ISR, by design, cannot fire unless an event has been triggered so the IRQ cannot be fired btwn two calls to the callback.

I might just be stuck with what I have?

Comment: The idea with a queue is to push to it from within `my_publish_data_cb()`, and pull from it in `my_get_data_cb()`. Similarly, you can pass the task handle in a global variable, or make `my_publish_data_cb` a lambda that captures it.